# Tools for information architecture mockups

Tags: mockup, information-architecture

I often find myself making very high-level sketches of UIs in order to illustrate information architectures. For example, I want to show that a certain page displays a certain kind of information, and links to certain other pages in certain ways. But I'm not really attempting to *design* anything: I ultimately hand these schematics over to a real designer, who is responsible for figuring out how to actually present the information on each page.

Can anyone recommend any tools for me to use at the "information architecture" level? To be clear, I do want to generate actual UI mockups, but I don't want to make any decisions about the design or layout of this information.

Comment: Google "wireframing software" and you'll find dozens of options...many of which include flow charting and the like.

Comment: Can you show one of your sketches as an example of your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest most commonly-used wireframing tool I know these days is called **[Sketch](https://www.sketchapp.com/)** - it's an app available on Windows, Linux and Mac, and has both a huge number of plugins and templates available.

It's commonly used in the UI / UX worlds, and a fair number of folks in both the design and coding side of webwork use it too, making handoff simple.